# how to load selected data from combo in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, combobox

In codeigniter i want to load my selected data in combo in edit case .How to do so? My code is like this

```
<?php
$extra=' class="selectCombo"';
$options = array(
    'yes'  => 'Active',
    'no'    => 'Inactive',
);
echo form_dropdown('user_status', $options, set_value('user_status'),$extra);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[set_value](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form)** Works repopulate the form field with the submitted data not for edit value from database

According to Codeigniter documentation of **[form_dropdown](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown)**

> The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second
>   parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third
>   parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected. You can also
>   pass an array of multiple items through the third parameter, and
>   CodeIgniter will create a multiple select for you.

By passing third parameter your select value

```
echo form_dropdown('user_status', $options,'yes' ,$extra);
```